# How do you regenerate autogenerated code in NetBeans?

Tags: java, user-interface, netbeans

1. Create a project in NetBeans and create a new JFrame.
2. Use the GUI Builder to drag some components like a button or label onto the frame and look and the source. You'll see by default that the member variables are private in the frame class.
3. Now go to Tools -> Options -> Misc -> GUI Builder and change something like the variables modifier to protected instead of private.

Now how do you apply those changes to the already generated code? I've tried several things like format code, fix code, etc. I've even tried cutting all the components off of the frame and then repasting them hoping to fix the issue, but it still uses the *old* settings.

When I create a new JFrame in the project and perform step 2 again, the changes have taken effect. Any *new* code generated on a *new* frame or file works as expected, but not the original.

This is very strange behavior, and I have to imagine there's an easy straight forward way to regenerate this code. Am I missing something?

I'm using NetBeans 7.1 and Java 7u2. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would really recommend not to use GUIBuilder. You have spotted one issue yourself. Also, the code generated for you cannot be edited. This was the way it was before, not sure now.  If you are not using a layout an relying on absolute positioning, then if the person resizes the screen then you have issues with your components going out of place. Instead learn how to use a good layout manager, likes jgoodies forms layout. Its very easy and will make your life a lot easier. http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/forms/index.html

Comment: Nice question! Unfortunately I'm pretty sure you can't do this. This fonctionnality don't seems to be done.

Comment: I believe my answer is a correct one for your question. Perhaps you could mark it so?

Answer (score 1):

As you have already alluded to, the GUI Builder options are *defaults* only, for the creation of the form.

You **can** change most things about already-generated GUI elements.

To change the GUI components 'access' from `private` to `protected`, right-click the component in the GUI designer and select "Customize Code". At the bottom of the "Code Customizer" dialog you can change just about any aspect of the declaration of the GUI element. That dialog also lets you customise things like the constructor used for the element.

I would recommend you leave the access default at `private`, and only change the elements that you really need to be `protected` or even `public`.

And don't listen to the doom-sayers. We have over 600 GUI-designed forms in our application, we use the GUI designer every day, with multiple developers, and we very rarely have any issues at all.

By the way, we are using version 6.9.1 of NetBeans with Java6, so YMMV.

Comment: LOL, "No issues at all."  We experience exactly the opposite here.

Comment: Perhaps you'd like to share the issues that you are having with the GUI Builder? Better yet, why not ask a question here on SO with a list of the issues that you have and ask if anyone has solutions to them. I'm pretty sure I could help with most of them. BTW, what version of NetBeans are you using?

Comment: BTW, over 1000 forms now and still no significant issues.

Comment: (1) For multiple versions, it was disrespecting the Beans.isDesignTime() flag, so it was impossible to edit any forms unless the components happened to work in NetBeans even with design-time turned off. (2) It inserts magic numbers for widths and heights into our layout code, which results in incorrect layout on any system other than the one you made the layout on. (3) It can't handle ComponentPlacement.INDENT whatsoever. (4) The code it generates is filled with unchecked warnings, forcing us to ignore all warnings, meaning that actual bugs are being masked.

Comment: (5) The method it uses for binding is unchecked and not checked at compile-time either, so if you rename a field in a model, nobody will ever know that you did, and the form will stop working "mysteriously." (6) It doesn't support binding on some properties which definitely have a setter, forcing us to add code for further bindings anyway. (7) The "automatic internationalisation" doesn't automatically internationalise all fields, only basic stuff like "text". (8) If you change any component class, you have to do a full recompile of the entire project, or the form won't even open.

Comment: (9) When you try to drag something to a logical position in the layout, sometimes it disregards your instructions completely and the entire layout breaks. The only way out of this seems to be to drag all the components out of the layout again and manually lay out the entire view again. (10) It allows developers to hide additional code inside obscure places, so that nobody can see that it's being run. And I guess my last complaint: (11) It isn't actually saving anybody time. The person who makes the form has their time wasted. The people who have to maintain the form have their time wasted.

Comment: As for the suggestion of posting questions about all the issues... I don't have enough time as there are too many. Rather, I would fire the question back - is there anything about this piece of shit which is actually helping me produce high quality user interfaces?